# Set default value to C array when used as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, default

I have the following function:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8 rgb[3]);
```

The problem is that I want `rgb` argument to have default value. Like that:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8 rgb[3]={255, 255, 255});
```

Unfortunately, the compiler does not like this? Is there another way?

Comment: `Uint8 rgb[3]` is not an array, so how is something like `Uint8 rgb[3]={255, 255, 255}` supposed to work? Is your actual question "How to pass an array in C++"?

Comment: The parameter is a pointer, not an array. The array syntax is just a hint to the humans reading the code.

Comment: You could use `std::array<Uint8, 3>` instead.

Comment: The title says C, but the tag says C++.  C does not support default values for parameters.

Comment: @Mawg The title says "C array", which is a common name for built-in arrays.

Comment: @Mawg pretty sure that OP by "C array" meant "C-style array"

Comment: Then it would not hurt to edit the title, because I , for one, took it as a C question, to which the correct answer would be "you cannot"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the parameter is a pointer, not an array.
To the compiler, the prototype is equivalent to

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8* rgb);
```

Overloading is one alternative:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8 rgb[3]);

void getDefaultMaterial()
{
    Uint8 rgb[3] = { 255, 255, 255 };
    getDefaultMaterial(rgb);
}
```

Although, if `rgb` is an "out" parameter, the point of this eludes me.

If it's not an "out" parameter, you *can* use an actual array with a default value, but you need to pass it by const reference:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(const Uint8 (&rgb)[3] = {255, 255, 255});
```

or, as an "out" parameter with "default by overloading":

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8 (&rgb)[3]);

void getDefaultMaterial()
{
    Uint8 rgb[3] = { 255, 255, 255 };
    getDefaultMaterial(rgb);
}
```

Comment: rgb is not out parameter, just dummy sample code :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively use a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) wrapper as a parameter:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(std::array<Uint8, 3> rgb = { { 255, 255, 255 } });
```

This will allow you to use the [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) as a default parameter value. Note that *double* braces are needed for C++11 standard only. In C++14 and later standards you can omit them:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(std::array<Uint8, 3> rgb = { 255, 255, 255 });
```

Comment: Also, with the `= {...}` syntax, brace elision should also work in C++11 iirc.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need the array as it decays to a pointer in function parameters. You can simply declare it as pointer and set its default to `nullptr` or whatever you like, and identify the defaulted address in the function.

For example:

```
void getDefaultMaterial(Uint8 *rgb = nullptr) {
    static Uint8 defaultArg[3] = {255, 255, 255};
    if (rgb == nullptr) {
        rgb = defaultArg;
        // Reset them if you need
    }
    // Your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "array" in question is a pointer, not an array. Using an actual array (which can only be passed by reference) instead works fine.

```
void fun (const int (&a)[3] = {1,2,3}) {
    std::cout << a[1];
}
```

Of course, the actual proper way is using `std::array`, which does not have all those limitations.